# how to get firebase value into array and how to delete by uuid?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am having an issue i can get the value from my realtime database. i'm using this function. bu maybe i'm doing something wrong

[image]

```
enter c func getPlays(handler: @escaping(_ boat: [GameToSend]) -> ()) {
    PLAYS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (playSnap) in
        var plays = [GameToSend]()
        guard let playsSnapShot = playSnap.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
        for play in playsSnapShot {
            print(play)
            let key = play.key
            let sport = play.childSnapshot(forPath: "sports").value as? String ?? ""
            let winLoss = play.childSnapshot(forPath: "winLoss").value as? String ?? ""
            let teams = play.childSnapshot(forPath: "teams").value as? String ?? ""
            let picks = play.childSnapshot(forPath: "picks").value as? String ?? ""
            let date = play.childSnapshot(forPath: "date").value as? String ?? ""
            let playsToSend = GameToSend(key: key, winLoss: winLoss, sport: sport, teams: teams, picks: picks, time: date   )
            plays.append(playsToSend)
        }
        handler(plays)
    }

}
```

here i want to delete by uuid instead of key

```
 func deleteDataforNotificationVC(key: String) {
    PICKS.child(key).removeValue()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you delete like this id here udid:

```
    func authenticateDeleteUserToken(email: String, password: String,id: String) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
        if let error = error {
            // An error happened.
            self.showAlert(withTitle: appConstants.KAppName.rawValue, message: error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // for User deletion.
            user?.user.delete { error in
                if let error = error {
                    // An error happened.
                    self.showAlert(withTitle: appConstants.KAppName.rawValue, message: error.localizedDescription)
                } else { //delete perticular id like child
              let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Users")
                    ref.child(id).removeValue { error, _ in
                    //success
                      }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```